# How to set time duration for an operation in android app?

Tags: android

I am developing flashlight app. I want to set time like 2mins, 3mins and unlimited for the flashlight to be on. How can I do that?
First of all I am checking whether flashlight is available or not. If it is, I want to set the brightness to maximum.

My code contains the following.

```
if (flashcheck) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = getWindow()
                    .getAttributes();
            localLayoutParams.screenBrightness = 1F;
            getWindow().setAttributes(localLayoutParams);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Handler for this, Check the below example:-

```
Handler handler=new Handler();handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// write the code here that will be executed after 2000 milliseconds.               
}

}, 2000);
```

Whatever Runnable object you will pass as handler's document, it will execute after 2000 milliseconds (means 2 seconds).

Comment: @MudhunVP Always Welcome ... :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use timers to schedule your on/off time like so.

The Java way to do this is by `java.util.Timer` & `java.util.TimerTask` this also works in Android.

You might want to try using a handler class `android.os.Handler` then you could send a message to the handler by `sendMessageAtTime(message, int)`

or like I have used before `sendMessageDelayed(message, int)`.

when you receive a message, you can run your task

in the 2nd option you would have to create a `Runnable object` and schedule it by the  Handler function `postAtTime(Runnable, int)` || `postDelayed(Runnable, int)`